# PhpStorm automatically upload to default server after update from SVN?

Tags: svn, automation, phpstorm, remote-host

I try to automate my project, for that i need exactly:


- update files from SVN

- upload **only** the changed files to default server


is there any way to do that over PhpStorm (*settings*..),

or does i need external tools for that?

thx for answers

Comment: well, if the 'upload changed files automatically to the default server' option in Settings/Deployment/Options is set to 'Always', changed files are auto-uploaded... There are no options related to Update though (like it's done for Commit, where you can choose to upload files to server right in the Commit dialog)

Comment: In my case that's not working. I'm using PHPStorm 7.0 (Build #PS-131.374), JRE 1.7.0_10. I have that option checked, also I've tried to check 'Overwrite up-to-date files', without success - after update muy files are not uploaded/overwritten if there are older version on server.

Comment: Same with PHPStorm 8 - I have that option selected. Also, I have local copy and files are going to mapped windows drive (with samba share) - unfortunately, auto-uploading didn't work. I must upload files manually, that'2 very very annoying if you have 4GB+ project.

Answer (score 5):

go to Tools -> Deployment -> Options and check the checkbox 'Upload external changes'.

Tada :)